# Service Stack (REST) SOAP and WSDL not working

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I implemented [ServiceStack Hello World](http://servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) ,every thing is ok,except one important thing.
its
SOAP11 and SOAP12 and also WSDL not working.
when accessing url http://localhost:8082/SOAP11/ for SOAP11 or SOAP12 it says :

```
{
"ResponseStatus":{
 "ErrorCode":"NotImplementedException",
 "Message":"The method or operation is not implemented.",
 "StackTrace":"   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName) in C:\\src\\ServiceStack\\src\\ServiceStack\\WebHost.EndPoints\\Support\\EndpointHandlerBase.cs:line 52\n   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.AppHostHttpListenerBase.ProcessRequest(HttpListenerContext context) in C:\\src\\ServiceStack\\src\\ServiceStack\\WebHost.EndPoints\\AppHostHttpListenerBase.cs:line 57\n   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.HttpListenerBase.ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) in C:\\src\\ServiceStack\\src\\ServiceStack\\WebHost.EndPoints\\Support\\HttpListenerBase.cs:line 197"
}
}
```

I implemented it via console host.
my console host class :

```
 public class AppHost
    : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public AppHost() //Tell ServiceStack the name and where to find your web services
        : base("ServiceStack Examples", typeof(InventoryREST.Hello).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
    }
}
```

and when I want to access it via WSDL , it shows nothing,just blank page and cpu is working ...

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the answer - however, please don't edit your question to mark it as "[SOLVED]" or to include the answer. Rather, the etiquette for answering one's own question is to post the answer as an answer, rather than to edit the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOAP endpoints are not available when hosted on a HttpListener Host (i.e. in a stand-alone Console).

You will need to host it in an ASP.NET host to view the XSD's and WSDLs.

Answer (score 3):

The Hello World Example project is actually hosted at `/servicestack/` so the correct urls would be:

Metadata page: 
http://localhost:8082/servicestack/metadata

SOAP 1.1 WSDL:
http://localhost:8082/servicestack/soap11

SOAP 1.2 WSDL:
http://localhost:8082/servicestack/soap12

Note: the WSDL endpoints above is also the Endpoints of your SOAP web services, i.e. your SOAP Client would **POST** SOAP messages to the above endpoints.

If you prefer they weren't hosted at a custom path, you will need to will need to change the Web.config to setup servicestack [listening on the root / path](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#rootpath).

Comment: my metadata works on http://localhost:8082/metadata/ , and my custom path is root,but still no SOAP.

Comment: I've just tried it, http://localhost:{port}/soap11 http://localhost:{port}/soap12 on WebDevServer and http://localhost/ServiceStack.Hello/soap11 http://localhost/ServiceStack.Hello/soap12 work for me on IIS. Can you post the Web.config you're using?

Comment: I'm not using IIS , I'm using console APP and microsoft HTTP API, (APPHTTPListenerBase)

Comment: I asked it in its google group and they said that WSDL is not supported on console host,its just supported on ASP.NET hosting. Thanks for your reply.